# Php string split manipulation

Tags: php, string

I am getting string result from a variable like this:

```
string(87) "Marko Petronijevic
asdas
Beograd, 12321
T: 1232321 "
```

Where the first line is First and Lastname, second and third line is Address and last line phone number.

Is it possible somehow to convert that string result to be:

```
First name: Marko Petronijevic
Address: asdas, Beograd, 12321
Phone: 1232321
```

I tried with explode function and it is ok:

```
array(7) { 
      [0]=> string(5) "Marko" 
      [1]=> string(26) "Petronijevic asdas" 
      [2]=> string(5) "22" 
      [3]=> string(18) "/> Beograd," 
      [4]=> string(0) ""
      [5]=> string(16) "12321 T:" 
      [6]=> string(11) "1232321 " 
      }
```

But the problem that I am facing is that I dont know if the name will have middlename, so I cannot for sure work with this array format.

Please, If anyone have some idea how to split this to be 100% accurate, let me know.

Comment: what will the string look like if it contains middle name?

Comment: i suggest you this reading: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/ , there will be no real arbitrary rule that will work 100% times. You should somewhat ask your customers to enter in 2 different inputs, and if you have no control on the input, that's hard to solve

Comment: If there is a middlename the result will be:First name: Marko Midlename Petronijevic
Address: asdas, Beograd, 12321
Phone: 1232321

Comment: @Milo .. Check My Ans ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string, and setup a little line configuration like this.

```
$string = "Marko Petronijevic
asdas
Beograd, 12321
T: 1232321";

$lines = [
 0 => 'Name',
 1 => 'Address',
 2 => 'Place',
 3 => 'Tel'
];

$array = explode("\n", $string);

if (count($lines) == count($array)) {
  $res = array_combine($lines, $array);
  print_r($res);
}
```

Result:
Array ( [Name] => Marko Petronijevic [Address] => asdas [Place] => Beograd, 12321 [Tel] => T: 1232321 )

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$str = "Marko Petronijevic asdas Beograd, 12321 T: 1232321 ";  // Your String

$divstr = explode(" ", $str);

echo 'First Name :'. $divstr[0];  // Marko
echo '<br>';
echo 'Middle Name :'.$divstr[1];   // Petronijevic
echo '<br>';
echo 'Address :'.$divstr[2] . $divstr[3] . $divstr[4];   //asdas /Beograd, // 12321
echo '<br>';
echo 'Phone :'.$divstr[6];  // T:1232321


?>
```

**Output:**

```
First Name :Marko
Middle Name :Petronijevic
Address :asdasBeograd,12321
Phone :1232321
```

**Working Demo :**  https://eval.in/823533

Answer (score -1):

You can split your string on every new line

```
  $your_array = explode("\n", $your_string);
```